# DRCsim Atlas robot inverse kinematics

Tags: gazebo, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

I am developing a simple application using DRCsim 2.3 (DARPA Robotics Challenge Simulator) and Gazebo 1.6 .

By now, in a simple application, I am trying to control only the robotic arms of ATLAS.
I want to place the robotic arms end links (l_hand and r_hand) in specific given poses of the workspace.

How can I do that using DRCsim and Gazebo + ROS?
I have read some suggestions related to the determination of inverse kinematics in other applications (PR2, etc) that have used the package
http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics

Should I follow the same approach for Atlas robot?
Or DRCsim integrates better (performance, accuracy) nativeinterfaces to control the ATLAS robot in Cartesian space? What are them?

Thanks for your attention and answers

Regards,
Ricardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2503/drcsim-atlas-robot-inverse-kinematics/) by [RFAM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/322/rfam/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prashant](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/386/prashant/) on 2013-06-08**:
Hi, were able to get the arm_kinematics package working for the finding the inverse kinematics of the Atlas arm??? I've been trying to do it myself for about a week now but without any luck?? If you were able to get it working could you please give me the steps on how you approached it. I am using ROS fuerte, Gazebo 1.8.2 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe late for some people but the solution We used for the VRC Qualifications can be found in this repository: https://bitbucket.org/fsuarez6/atlas-arm-manipulation

`arm_kinematics_tools` ([wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics_tools)) is the package used for solving the kinematics.

---

Originally posted by [Francisco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/314/francisco/) with karma: 143 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RFAM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/322/rfam/) on 2013-07-03**:
Thanks.

Best regards,
Ricardo Martins